# Cannot unzip the artifact downloaded

Tags: github-actions

My workflow has 2 jobs:

- job "build" creates a zip and uploads it as an artifact
- job "deploy" downloads this artifact and (tries to) unzip it

Here is a simplified version of the workflow:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
    - name: action-zip
      uses: montudor/action-zip@v1.0.0
      with:
        args: zip -qq -r azfunc-repository-stats.zip .

    - name: Upload artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: azfunc-repository-stats-app
        path: ${{ github.workspace }}/azfunc-repository-stats.zip

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Download artifact'
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: azfunc-repository-stats-app
        path: ${{ runner.temp }}

    - name: Debug
      run: |
        ls -al ${{ runner.temp }}
        id
        chmod 777 ${{ runner.temp }}/azfunc-repository-stats.zip
        cp ${{ runner.temp }}/azfunc-repository-stats.zip ${{ runner.temp }}/azfunc-repository-stats2.zip
        ls -al ${{ runner.temp }}
        
    - name: 'Unzip project'
      uses: montudor/action-zip@v1.0.0
      with:
        args: unzip -qq ${{ runner.temp }}/azfunc-repository-stats.zip -d ${{ github.workspace }}
```

Everything works fine (including `Debug` step), up to the step `Unzip project` which fails with this error :
`unzip:  cannot find or open /home/runner/work/_temp/azfunc-repository-stats.zip, /home/runner/work/_temp/azfunc-repository-stats.zip.zip or /home/runner/work/_temp/azfunc-repository-stats.zip.ZIP.`
I know it exists because my `Debug` step does output it, and can find/copy it with no problem

It is exactly the same problem if:

- I download the archive in `${{ github.workspace }}` instead of `${{ runner.temp }}`
- I use action `TonyBogdanov/zip@1.0` instead of `montudor/action-zip@v1.0.0` to unzip the artifact

Comment: Can you please remove the `-qq` option from unzip and then show complete logs from the debug and unzip step?

Comment: Hmm, stackoverflow does not allow me to copy too many lines of log.
I just made the test without the `-qq` and you can view the output at https://github.com/Yvand/azfunc-repository-stats/runs/4432232206?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: the directory you're referencing is on the github runner, but unzip is running in a container and that path doesn't exist there. you probably want to use a relative path or make sure to use an absolute path that exists in the container.

Comment: I didn't have time yet to test but that must be it, nice catch, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The download step already unzipped your artifact and this is why you cannot find this file.

So `${{ runner.temp }}/azfunc-repository-stats.zip` is a directory not this zip file.

Please check it via `${{ runner.temp }}/azfunc-repository-stats.zip -l` command.